# How to test with different versions of PHP in a GitHub Action

Tags: php, github, github-actions

I have some PHP code with tests which run using `PHPUnit` and wanted to test it on `GitHub Actions`. I could not find a method in their documentation for testing PHP packages.
I want to test using different versions of PHP, but they only have the latest one `7.3` installed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add the [setup-php](https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php) action in your workflow. If not present, it installs the PHP version(s) you specify with required extensions and various tools like composer. It supports all the virtual environments supported by GitHub Actions and PHP versions >= `5.3`.

For example you can have a workflow like this

```yaml
jobs:
  run:    
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.operating-system }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        operating-system: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macOS-latest]
        php-versions: ['7.2', '7.3']
    name: PHP ${{ matrix.php-versions }} Test on ${{ matrix.operating-system }}
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install PHP
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      with:
        php-version: ${{ matrix.php-versions }}
        extensions: intl #optional
        ini-values: "post_max_size=256M" #optional
    - name: Check PHP Version
      run: php -v
```

Note: This will setup PHP, you need to add steps to install your dependencies using `composer` and another step to run your tests using `PHPUnit`

You can specify the required extensions in the `extensions` and the `php.ini` configuration you want in `ini-values`. Both these inputs are optional and take a CSV as an input. The `php-version` input is required. In above example it will run the workflow and setup the PHP environment with the versions specified in `matrix.php-versions` i.e `7.2` and `7.3`, you can adjust these as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something exactly like this.

Comment: @Shivam Mathur I've used your package setup-php@v2 and specified `7.3`, and then checked the version afterwards. Confirmed is running `7.3`, but my composer install step directly afterwards fails and tells me I am on `7.4.10`. How is this possible if the previous step `php -v` tells me `7.3.10`?

Comment: @simonw16 
Are you using another action to install composer dependencies. 
If yes, it might be a docker based action while setup-php runs on the host container. I would suggest calling the composer command directly.

If not, please create an issue here specifying your workflow.
https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php/issues

Comment: @simonw16 same for your test suite. For example, if you use PHPunit, call that directly as well.

Comment: Thats exactly what the issue was! Took me hours to figure this out. I thought the actions were on the host container, but turns out they're mostly in their own. Running manually solved it. Thanks!